# Find the error of $w_a = \frac{0.2312-123.1}{1.52}$ where all the values were obtained by rounding

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation

$$w_a = \frac{0.2312-123.1}{1.52}$$

My professor told me to use Taylor series/the formula for the propagation of the error:
$f(x)-f(x_a) = f'(x_a)*(x-x_a)$ but I am not sure know how to apply it here.

I did:

$$w = f(x,y,z) = \frac{x-y}{z}$$

$$|E(x_a)| \le 0.5*10^{-4} \\
|E(y_a)| \le 0.5 * 10^{-1} \\
|E(z_a)| \le 0.5*10^{-2} \\
f_x = 1/z\\
f_y = -1/z \\
f_z = -\frac{x-y}{z^2}\\
|E(w_a)| = f_x(x_a)E(x_a)+f_yE(y_a)+f_z(z_a)E(z_a) \Leftrightarrow \\
|E(w_a)| \le (\frac{1}{1.52})(0.5*10^{-4})+ (-\frac{1}{1.52})(0.5*10^{-1})+ (-\frac{0.2312-123.1}{(1.52)^2})(0.5*10^{-2}) = .233$$

Looks wrong. Help?

Comment: You forgot to multiply by $E(z_a)$ in the last term?

Comment: @Mason Fixed it.